# Express prevent redirect in SPA

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, redirect

I have the following routes configuration:

```
const app = express();

app.use('/site', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../site/static')));
app.use('/site*', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../site/static')));
```

Now when I am accessing the app `http://localhost:8080/site/bla?asdad` I am being redirected to `http://localhost:8080/site/bla/?asdad` (note the slash that was added before the question mark).

The application is written with angular (1) and it causes the router (ui-router) to go to the default router.

When navigating within the app (clicking the links to different states) it all works correctly but on refresh the slash is added and redirects to the default route.

I have tried to add `{redirect: false}` to the static middelware options but it caused this url `http://localhost:8080/site/bla/?asdad` to return:

```
Cannot GET /site/bla
```

What should I do to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me:

```
app.use('/site', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../site/static')));

app.use('/site*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname, '../../site/static/index.html');
});
```